# can't save boolean value using "save" method JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to save **boolean value** using **save method** from **JPA**, but it seems like that I'm doing something wrong. I was searching this question and found general information about **NullPointerException**, but it doesn't solve and explain my situation. I tried to look at implementation of *save method*, but i didn't understand why it could throw this error. Please help me to solve it.

It gives next error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.demo.Entity.Category.getId(Category.java:31) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl$BeanPropertyHandler.getValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:308) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.getPropertyValue(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:52) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.getId(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:162) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation.isNew(AbstractEntityInformation.java:42) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.isNew(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:553) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.demo.Service.CategoryService.save(CategoryService.java:19) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.demo.Controller.CategoryController.insert(CategoryController.java:39) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_272]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_272]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_272]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_272]
```

My Category entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "is_available")
    private boolean isAvailable;
    // setters and getters, contrusctor
```

My Category Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/category")
public class CategoryController {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    // API to find all items
    @GetMapping("/")
    private List<Category> index(){
        return categoryService.findAll();
    }

    // API to find item by id
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    private Optional<Category> search(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return categoryService.findById(id);
    }

    // API to change item by id
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    private Category changeById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody Category category) throws Exception {
        categoryService.changeById(id, category);
        return category;
    }

    // API to create item
    @PostMapping
    private void insert(@RequestBody Category category) {
        categoryService.save(category);
    }

    // API to delete item by id
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    private void delete(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        categoryService.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

My Category Service

```
@Service
public class CategoryService {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    // Method to save
    public void save(Category category) {
        categoryRepository.save(category);
    }

    // Method to delete
    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        categoryRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    // Method to find all items from table
    public List<Category> findAll() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }

    // Method to find by id
    public Optional<Category> findById(Integer id) {
        return categoryRepository.findById(id);
    }

    // Method to change item by id
    public Category changeById (Integer id, Category newCategory) throws Exception {
        return categoryRepository.findById(id)
                .map(category -> {
                    category.setName(newCategory.getName());
                    category.setAvailable(newCategory.isAvailable());

                    return categoryRepository.save(category);
                }).orElseThrow(Exception::new);
    }
}
```

I'm using *Postman* to send *POST request*. There is my request:
[image]

Comment: Add a break point here `categoryService.save(category);` and check that `category` is really set

Comment: "at com.example.demo.Entity.Category.getId" - that seems like a nullpointer is happening inside the getter method - that makes it unwise to cut the getter out of the posted code. I can make a guess that the getter returns an int instead of an Integer; that will trigger an NPE when the ID is null since autoboxing cannot be done on a null value.

Comment: @Gimby, sorry for late answer for you reply. Yes, it works for me, thank you! I don't know why, but when i was creating "getter" and "setter" methods i used "generator of methods", i checked my fields and there was "Integer id" and don't know why "generator" created "get" method with "int" type.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't put an entity jpa right inside my controller as request body. You shall distinguish layers and create single-responsability. A dto is a thing, an entity to be persisted onto the database is another thing.
Having said that, the stacktrace is telling you, by

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.demo.Entity.Category.getId(Category.java:31) ~[main/:na]
```

that at the very moment the repo is checking for the id of your java entity, it is finding the object Category to be null, since the getter, unless you've implemented it in a certain way, shall be a simple:

```
public Integer getId(){
   return this.id;
}
```

thus "this" is being null. As I would suggest, create two separated concepts, as for the dto coming from the REST call and as for the JPA entity, and finally map  fields one each other. Eventually, put some logs into your code to make sure your objects are being instantiated and valued correctly.

Comment: I don't get you what do you mean by saying "as for the dto coming from the REST call and as for the JPA entity", how should it look like? Can you please provide me with some guide?

Comment: I meant you shall have a DTO (data transfer object) java class, in which you'll put json request body. Then might need a factory, in which you map the DTO to a java MODEL (the JPA entity IS actually a model), and then use the model in your business logic. A model is a pojo class where you can find all of the fields you can use in your business logic level, i.e. a full JPA entity with all its fields. A dto generally contains only the request or response (this one called generally RESOURCE) body to and from a REST, SOAP or similar calls.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object